# Native libraries .so.XY failing to link at runtime

Tags: android, shared-libraries, native

I have built FFmpeg for Android and want to use it in an application like so:

```
System.loadLibrary("avutil");
System.loadLibrary("swscale");
System.loadLibrary("avcodec");
System.loadLibrary("avformat");
```

The build output are `lib*.so`, `lib*.so.MAJOR` and `lib*.so.MAJOR.MINOR.OTHER` files. Inside the shared objects are references like `lib*.so.MAJOR`, for example `libswscale.so.2` requires `libavutil.so.52`.

Now if I put the `*.so` files in the project's `libs` folder (more exactly `libs/armeabi-v7a`), I of course get

> 01-25 12:06:40.270: E/AndroidRuntime(2905): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1936]:   107 could not load needed library 'libavutil.so.52' for 'libswscale.so' (load_library[1091]: Library 'libavutil.so.52' not found)

However if instead I put the `*.so.MAJOR` files in the `libs` folder to solve the linking exception, I get the same error when running the app from Eclipse. And I noticed the files do not even get exported if I create an APK! **So how do I tell Eclipse to package the `*.so.MAJOR` files as libraries?** Or alternatively, how do I compile the shared objects in a way that they reference each other by `*.so` instead of `*.so.MAJOR`?

EDIT: It seems there's no way to package `*.so.XYZ` files [automatically](http://en.usenet.digipedia.org/thread/12874/9875/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't find a solution to take the `.so.MAJOR` files as I wished. It seems to me that the Android build system only copies `*.so` files automatically and doesn't allow other file extensions.
So I rewrote the FFmpeg makefiles to have the shared objects reference each other by `libXXX.so`.

In `library.mak`, I replaced `$(SHFLAGS)` in the following recipe

```
$(SUBDIR)$(SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR): $(OBJS) $(SUBDIR)lib$(NAME).ver
    $(SLIB_CREATE_DEF_CMD)
    $$(LD) $(SHFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $$(LD_O) $$(filter %.o,$$^) $(FFEXTRALIBS)
    $(SLIB_EXTRA_CMD)
```

so that the third line looks like

```
$(subst $$(@F),$(SLIBNAME),$(SHFLAGS))
```

For those who don't understand the substitution (like me before), check [this directly related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14522778/245706).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need to do that.
What you need to do is edit the configure file.
And find out this:

```
SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR='$(SLIBNAME).$(LIBMAJOR)'
LIB_INSTALL_EXTRA_CMD='$$(RANLIB) "$(LIBDIR)/$(LIBNAME)"'
SLIB_INSTALL_NAME='$(SLIBNAME_WITH_VERSION)'
SLIB_INSTALL_LINKS='$(SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR) $(SLIBNAME)'
```

Modified them to be:

```
SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR='$(SLIBPREF)$(FULLNAME)-$(LIBMAJOR)$(SLIBSUF)'
LIB_INSTALL_EXTRA_CMD='$$(RANLIB) "$(LIBDIR)/$(LIBNAME)"'
SLIB_INSTALL_NAME='$(SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR)'
SLIB_INSTALL_LINKS='$(SLIBNAME)'
```