# Simple string substitution in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, substitution

I want to replace the string `libswscale.so.2` by `libswscale.so` (variables called `$(SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR)` and `$(SLIBNAME)`, respectively). This is what I tried in the Makefile:

```
$(SUBDIR)$(SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR): $(OBJS) $(SUBDIR)lib$(NAME).ver
    [...]
    @echo SHFLAGS=$(SHFLAGS)
    @echo SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR=$(SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR)
    @echo SLIBNAME=$(SLIBNAME)
    @echo A $(patsubst $(SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR),$(SLIBNAME),$(SHFLAGS))
    @echo B $(SHFLAGS:$(SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR)=$(SLIBNAME))
    @echo C $($(SHFLAGS):$(SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR)=$(SLIBNAME))
    @echo D $(SHFLAGS:$(SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR)=$(SLIBNAME))
    @echo E $(subst $(SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR),$(SLIBNAME),$(SHFLAGS))
    @echo F $(subst l,L,$(SHFLAGS))
```

The output is

```
SHFLAGS=-shared -Wl,-soname,libswscale.so.2 -Wl,-Bsymbolic -Wl,--version-script,libswscale/libswscale.ver
SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR=libswscale.so.2
SLIBNAME=libswscale.so
A -shared -Wl,-soname,libswscale.so.2 -Wl,-Bsymbolic -Wl,--version-script,libswscale/libswscale.ver
B -shared -Wl,-soname,libswscale.so.2 -Wl,-Bsymbolic -Wl,--version-script,libswscale/libswscale.ver
C
D -shared -Wl,-soname,libswscale.so.2 -Wl,-Bsymbolic -Wl,--version-script,libswscale/libswscale.ver
E -shared -Wl,-soname,libswscale.so.2 -Wl,-Bsymbolic -Wl,--version-script,libswscale/libswscale.ver
F -shared -WL,-soname,libswscale.so.2 -WL,-BsymboLic -WL,--version-script,LibswscaLe/LibswscaLe.ver
```

The last one (F) is especially ridiculous. What is wrong here? Is it because `$(SHFLAGS)` is made up of variables as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it: `$(SHFLAGS)` was defined as

```
SHFLAGS=-shared -Wl,-soname,$$(@F) blablafoo
```

and using any substitution on it would not work until `$$(@F)` is actually evaluated (in my case to `libswscale.so.2`).

I solved it by replacing the variable reference:

```
@echo $(subst $$(@F),$(SLIBNAME),$(SHFLAGS))
```

---

Small hint on assignments: `VAR = $(OTHERVAR)` is evaluated when used, `VAR := $(OTHERVAR)` is evaluated immediately.